# A regressor failed to learn extreme values

Tags: regression, outliers, ensemble-learning, boosting

I am working on a regression problem using xgbclassifier (https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html)

The output values range from 0 to 10 (log-normal distribution), but when I predicted on the testset, the output is always around 4-6. The regressor seems not to learn the examples at extreme values.

I tried several ways:

- oversampling the training instances with high output values.
- put instance weight on the training set.

But none of them works.

Might you suggest some approaches to deal with the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try switching to another model, e.g. Adaboost.

> Models like AdaBoost increase the weights of misclassified points on every iteration and therefore might put high weights on these outliers as they tend to be often misclassified. This can become an issue if that outlier is an error of some type, or if we want our model to generalize well and not care for extreme values.

[Adaboost and outliers](https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/how-to-make-your-machine-learning-models-robust-to-outliers-44d404067d07)

Comment: I already used `xgboost` with the same principle. Not sure if Adaboost can help?